# Extension for CGColor with Error 'init(red:green:blue:alpha) is unavailable'

Tags: swift, init, cgcolor

I am a little lost here. I am writing an extension to CGColor which returns a CGColor from a hex value (String) and an optional alpha value (CGFloat). On returning the new CGColor instance, the following error occurs:

```
'init(red:gee:blue:alpha)' is unavailable
```

The following info ist given:

1. 'init(red:green:blue:alpha:)' has been explicitly marked unavailable here (CoreGraphics.CGColor)

Here is the complete extension code:

```swift
import Foundation
import CoreGraphics

extension CGColor {

    /// Construct a CGColor from a hex value and an optional alpha value.
    ///
    /// - Parameter hex: The hex value to use for the rgb value, must be in the form of "#ffffff"
    /// - Parameter alpha: Optional alpha value, ranges from 0 to 1.0
    ///
    /// - Returns: A CGColor or nil if the provided hex value is invalid.
    static func from(hex: String, alpha: CGFloat = 1.0) -> CGColor? {

        // not a hex value: missing prefix or invalid character count
        guard hex.hasPrefix("#") || hex.count == 7 else {
            return nil
        }

        let start = hex.index(hex.startIndex, offsetBy: 1)
        let hexColor = String(hex[start...])

        let scanner = Scanner(string: hexColor)
        var hexNumber: UInt64 = 0

        scanner.scanHexInt64(&hexNumber)

        let r = CGFloat((hexNumber & 0xff000000) >> 16) / 255
        let g = CGFloat((hexNumber & 0x00ff0000) >> 8) / 255
        let b = CGFloat(hexNumber & 0x0000ff00) / 255

        // here comes the error: 'init(red:green:blue:alpha)' is unavailable
        return CGColor(
            red: r,
            green: g,
            blue: b,
            alpha: alpha
        )
    }
}
```

[Edit]

For Context: This code is part of an universal framework targeting iOS and macOS. This framework parses a (huge) bunch of text files describing geometry and color objects. Color are provided as hex values.

This CGColor extension is used to return a CGColor from the parsed hex value.

Some example from the code:

```swift
// the geometry object, which has a color
public struct Geometry {
    public let color: Color
}

// the color definition for the geometry object
public struct Color {
    public let id: ColorID
    public let value: String
    public let alpha: Int

    // some code left out

    public var cgColor: CGColor {
        return CGColor?.from(hex: value, alpha: alphaValue)
    }
}
```

If the app, which uses the framework, needs a color:

```swift
let geometry = fromParsingFramework.geometry()
if let color = geometry.color.cgColor
```

Comment: You are missing part of the error: *"init(red:green:blue:alpha:) is unavailable in iOS"*. It's only for macOS.

Comment: are you trying to basically have a way to change say an objects background color using rgb values?

Comment: @maddy: the extension is used in a custom universal framework, iOS and macOS

Comment: @Mike: I need the CGColor later on in a SceneKit app. I basically have a bunch of text files which describe geometry objects. One part is the color of the object described as a hex value. From parsing of these files I want to use the hex value directly to assign a CGColor.

Comment: How are you using this extension in your code?

Comment: I am using it as the color value in a struct. ```public var color: CGColor {
        return CGColor?.from(hex: value, alpha: alphaValue)
    }``` -> da**it, can't include code here.

Comment: If you cannot post code here, I recommend you edit your question and add how you are implementing your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since that initializer is only for macOS, you can replace that with the following:

```
let comps = [r,g,b,alpha]
return CGColor(colorSpace: CGColorSpace(name: CGColorSpace.sRGB)!, components: comps)
```

If your framework only needs to support iOS 13+/macOS 10.15+ then you can use the new initializer:

```
return CGColor(srgbRed: r, green: g, blue: b, alpha: alpha)
```

Comment: In iOS 13 he could use `init(srgbRed red: CGFloat, green: CGFloat, blue: CGFloat, alpha: CGFloat)`.

Comment: @matt Yes, if the OP is only supporting iOS 13/macOS 10.15 and later for their framework then that would be a good alternative.

Comment: @maddy:I just looked up the documentation. There is no mention that CGColor init(red:green:bblue:alpha) is only available in macOS. It even states under Frameworks: iOS2+ . Could you explain, please.

Comment: @dirk See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgcolor/1455631-init